# More Efficient way to get and compare non-concurrent fields Google Sheets (Google App Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am working on a solution that is essentially a change log, I am using the edit event trigger to capture the data that is being changed. After that I need to create a separate sheet that essentially shows a singular row for each person that had data changed but the data presented is the most current data. So if the unique id already exists on the sheet it is first deleted and then the new data is moved into the sheet.

The script i have is working but as it is not efficient it is possible for the users doing the input to "beat" the program run time.

The only solution I can think of is to read the values into an array but as i am new to the programing world and app script so i'm positive there is a solution that i am just not aware of yet.

Open to any ideas!

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName(); 
  var sNameActive = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  if(sName == "D_Comp") { // enter the if statement only if changes we made on a sheet not named logging
    var value;
    var mA1 = e.range.getA1Notation().split(":")[0]; //range of change in A1 notation. 
    var col = e.range.getColumn(); // column number of where change occured
    var row = e.range.getRow(); // row number of where the change occured
    var time = new Date().toTimeString();   // time the change was made
    var user = e.user; 
    var oldvalue; // defining the variable that will store the old value within the sheet 
    oldvalue = e.oldValue; // old value that was in the cell before hand 
    var aCell = e.source.getRange(mA1);
    value = aCell.getValue(); 
    var colhdr = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, col).getValue(); // getting the header value
    var Emplid = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1).getValue(); // getting the emplid
    var GUID = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 2).getValue(); // getting the GUID
    var effdate= ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 28).getValue(); // getting the change date
    var Salary = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 44).getValue(); // get base salary value for workers row
    var Location = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 36).getValue(); // get location value for workers row
    var Department = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 16).getValue(); // get department numerical value for workes row
    var DepName = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 17).getValue(); // get departmner name for workers row
    var SOB = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 48).getValue(); // get phone stipend value for workers row
    var Stp_phone = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 50).getValue(); // get phone stipend value for workers row
    var Stp_home = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 51).getValue(); // get home stipend for workers home
    var Chng_rsn = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 29).getValue();


    if(oldvalue == undefined) { // we are replacing any underfined old value with a blank
      oldvalue = '';
    }


    var data = [GUID, time, oldvalue, value, colhdr, user]; // output into table on Logging sheet 
    e.source.getSheetByName("Logging").appendRow(data);

    var comp_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Comp_Changes") //setting the variable of comp_sheet to the comp_Change_full_rows
    var data2 = [Emplid, GUID, Chng_rsn, effdate, Salary, Location, Department, DepName, SOB, Stp_phone, Stp_home]; // populating the array data2
    var lastrow = comp_sheet.getLastRow();


    //loop to check if the emplid already exists on the comp final change sheet or not
    for (var x = 1; x <= lastrow; x++){
      var eval_emplid = comp_sheet.getRange(x, 1).getValue(); 

      //if a match is found, delete the old row
      if (eval_emplid == Emplid) {
        comp_sheet.deleteRow(x);
      }
    }

    comp_sheet.appendRow(data2); // appending the comp full rows sheet with the data in data2
  }
}
```

Comment: You definitely need to reduce calls to the spreadsheet service. A single `getRange` plus `getValues` can read in an entire row of data, and you can still create your shorthand variables based on the indices. Just note that `e.user` has restrictions on when it gets populated.

Comment: Ahh.. so put the entire row into an array and then assign the individual variables once the values are in the array. That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: a shorthand for all data on the sheet is `getDataRange().getValues()`. If you only need a subset of the data, and don't need the underlying range, you can use `getSheetValues()`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i changed the code to store the entire row into an array and then make the variable assignments from there. Processing time is down to about 3 seconds when it was 7 or 8 before. So thank you very much.

Comment: You can similarly benefit from reading all of `comp_sheet` into an array, and making your comparisons in it. Just note you'll need to track how many rows have been deleted to remain "synced" between your Array and the actual sheet (since you're modifying what you're iterating). Alternately, increment the iterator only if you don't perform a deletion.